# Edit Links commands are not visible in the Quick Launch and Top Navigation menu in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I have сreated custom site definition for SharePoint 2013, but for some reasons Edit Links command is not visible in the Quick Launch and Top Navigation menu. These commands available by default if I create a new Team Site. Is anybody know which feature I need activate in order to enable this cute functionality in my custom site template?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure of the solution, but the same problem exists when you create a site based on the Blank site template.

Comment: Also on Publishing Portal template

Answer (score 1):

The "Edit Links" with drag-and-drop is only supported by certain site definitions:  see [here](http://sharepintblog.com/2013/04/26/sharepoint-edit-links-drag-and-drop-navigation-option-missing/)

Edit:  The original blog site is no longer available, but the list of supported site definitions as originally published is:

`Team Site – STS#0
My Site Host – SPSSITEHOST#0
SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space – SPSPERS#0
Storage And Social SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space – SPSPERS#2
Storage Only SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space – SPSPERS#3
Social Only SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space – SPSPERS#4
Empty SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space – SPSPERS#5
Project Site – PROJECTSITE#0`

Comment: I have one site (on my dev machine) with WebTemplate BLANKINTERNET that has "Edit Links" and another site (test machine) that does not have "Edit links"

Comment: @willman link broken, pls give more info

Comment: Unfortunately, the original blog is no longer published.  I will Edit the answer to include the list of supported site definition, but you can find an archived version of the original post at https://web.archive.org/web/20160405002939/http://sharepintblog.com/2013/04/26/sharepoint-edit-links-drag-and-drop-navigation-option-missing/

Answer (score 0):

The only way how to enable them in Publishing sites is to give users "Manage Web Site" permissions.